# Java script no executing in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a javascript image slider on a basic rails app. I added the JS file to `assets/javascripts` folder but my javascript is not executing.

I added my html file below. Can anyone one please tell me what am I missing?

```
<div class="slider">
        <!-- Slideshow 3 -->
        <script>
            // You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
            $(function () {
              // Slideshow 3
              $("#slider3").responsiveSlides({
                manualControls: '#slider3-pager',
              });
            });
          </script>
        <ul class="rslides" id="slider3">
        <li>
            <div class="banner">
                <h1>What a beautiful bike</h1>
                <h2>timeless, atmospheric<br>& uncredible bikes!</h2>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="banner banner2">
                <h1>What a beautiful bike</h1>
                <h2>timeless, atmospheric<br>& uncredible bikes!</h2>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="banner banner1">
                <h1>What a beautiful bike</h1>
                <h2>timeless, atmospheric<br>& uncredible bikes!</h2>
            </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="slider3-pager">
          <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/device3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/device2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/device1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Which Rails version?

Comment: Have you required the asset in `assets/javascript/application.js`? Should be required with `//= require file_name`

Comment: Rails 5.1.1 and yes I added the required line on application.js but still nothing happening :/